# Dynamically added select list not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**TASK:**
Create second select list dynamically depending on option from the first list. For testing purposes i have attached the simple scenario.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("select[name='optionone']").on('change',function(){           
                var option = $("select[name='optionone']").val();               
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "data.php",
                    data: "option="+option,
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#ajaxcall").html(response);
                        $("#ajaxcall").show();
                    }
                });         
            });

            $('#ajaxcall').on('change', function(){
                $("select[name='optiontwo']").on('change', function () {
                    var optionone = $("select[name='optionone']").val();                            
                    var optiontwo = $("select[name='optiontwo']").val();    
                    console.log(optionone +'|||'+ optiontwo)            
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "data.php",
                        data: "optionone="+optionone+"&optiontwo="+optiontwo,
                        success: function(response){
                            $("#ajaxcall").html(response);
                            $("#ajaxcall").show();
                        }
                    });         
                });
            });         
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
Option one: 
<select name="optionone">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

<div id="ajaxcall" style="display:none">    

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**DATA.php**

```
Option two: 
<select name="optiontwo">
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="8">Option 8</option>
</select>
<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>
```

**PROBLEM:**
Second list named `optiontwo` will get attached as should. However, when I now select option from it, some option will work (for example `Option 5` and `Option 6`) while `Option 7` will not work (it will not make AJAX call). I have no idea what can cause this behavior.

I have noticed that if I remove AJAX call from second list, and add alert('changed') like this:

```
$('#ajaxcall').on('change', function(){
    $("select[name='optiontwo']").on('change', function () {
        alert('changed')                    
    });
});
```

and change `optiontwo` few times, then it will call alert few times. I have no idea if this is normal behavior or not either.

**QUESTION:**
How to get this thing working?

Comment: Use a dynamic event handler for `optiontwo` instead of using the unreliable `change` event of the `div` element.

Comment: **SIDE NOTE** if you want the page to load faster put al scripts just before `</body>` this way the page will be rendered before the javascript is loaded. This way you will already see some content instead of waiting for javascript to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a *delegate* event for the `optiontwo` select:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("select[name='optionone']").on('change',function(){           
            var option = $("select[name='optionone']").val();               
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.php",
                data: "option="+option,
                success: function(response){
                    $("#ajaxcall").html(response);
                    $("#ajaxcall").show();
                }
            });         
        });

        $('#ajaxcall').on('change', "select[name='optiontwo']", function () {
            var optionone = $("select[name='optionone']").val();                            
            var optiontwo = $("select[name='optiontwo']").val();    
            console.log(optionone +'|||'+ optiontwo)            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.php",
                data: "optionone="+optionone+"&optiontwo="+optiontwo,
                success: function(response){
                    $("#ajaxcall").html(response);
                    $("#ajaxcall").show();
                }
            });         
        });         
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `id` to call ajax and move the optionTwo ajax call to `data.php`. Try as below :

**First Page**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#optionone").on('change',function(){           
                var option = $("select[name='optionone']").val();               
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "data.php",
                    data: "option="+option,
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#ajaxcall").html(response);
                        $("#ajaxcall").show();
                    }
                });         
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
Option one: 
<select id="optionone" name="optionone">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<div id="ajaxcall" style="display:none">    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.php**

```
Option two: 
<select id="optiontwo" name="optiontwo">
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="8">Option 8</option>
</select>
<?php var_dump($_GET) ?>
<script>
$("#optiontwo").on('change', function () {
    var optionone = $("select[name='optionone']").val();                            
    var optiontwo = $("select[name='optiontwo']").val();    
    console.log(optionone +'|||'+ optiontwo)            
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.php",
        data: "optionone="+optionone+"&optiontwo="+optiontwo,
        success: function(response){
            $("#ajaxcall").html(response);
            $("#ajaxcall").show();
        }
    });         
});
</script>
```

Also add a blank option in `optiontwo` drop down.

Comment: Thanks for providing your answer! It is working, however i have accepted another answer as it is more suitable for me. Sorry about this!